# Trouble refreshing partial using AJAX and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm kind of new to web development, and I'm currently working on a simple project for Rails. Right now, I have a database with entries that all have an entry date, and I have an index page that displays all the entries for the current week, which works fine.

The next step is to implement a method for the user to select a week (currently using the jQuery UI datepicker) and then click a button, which automatically refreshes the partial on the index page to display the entries for that week.

Here's what I have so far:

In /app/views/reports/index.html.erb

```
<script>$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));
});</script>
<% require 'date' %>
<h1>Listing reports</h1>

<input type="datetime" id="datepicker" /> <%= button_to "Select Date", :action =>     'showEntries', :remote => 'true' %>

<div id="displayReports">
<%= render 'display', :date => Date.today %>
</div>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path %>
<%= link_to 'Send Weekly Email', weekly_email_reports_path %>
```

In /app/views/reports/_display.html.erb

```
<% require 'date' %>
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>App</th>
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
    <th>Planned</th>
    <th>Releases</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @reports.each do |report| %>
<% if report.entrydate.strftime('%U') == date.strftime('%U') %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= report.app %></td>
    <td><%= report.entrydate %></td>
    <td><%= report.completed %></td>
    <td><%= report.planned %></td>
    <td><%= report.releases %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', report %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_report_path(report) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', report, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

In /app/controllers/reports/showEntries.js.erb

```
var selectDate = $("#datepicker").val();
$("#displayReports").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'display', :locals => { :date => " + selectDate + " })).html_safe %>");
```

In /config/routes.rb

```
Summary::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :reports do
    collection do
      get 'weekly_email'
      post 'showEntries'
    end
  end

  get "home/index"
end
```

When I try to run the page, I get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"showEntries", :remote=>"true", :controller=>"reports"}
```

A lot of the questions similar to this question haven't really helped me. If you could point out what I'm doing wrong or a site to read up on Rails AJAX calls, that'd be great. Thanks. <3

Comment: Have you declared the route matching ReportsController#showEntries in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did. I just edited the post with my routes.rb file, as well.

Comment: can you try this: `<%= button_to "Select Date", {:action =>     'showEntries'}, :remote => 'true' %>` please? Its weird its like your button is trying to add a `params[:remote]` on the url instead of putting it has HTML... Can you post the output of your button_to also?

Comment: The output to my button_to is `<form class="button_to" method="post" data-remote="true" action="/reports/showEntries">
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Select Date">
<input type="hidden" value="SiJ725k8z2bIDkg1Z8fe62lNXkOW3mpp/UeLLdb7iPY=" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
</form>`
What you posted fixed the routing problem, it seems, but it still doesn't seem to be refreshing the div when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the name of the action showEntries to show_entries. I guess you have a action show_entries in your controller and misspelled it in the routes.